# Is using cat command to merge files created by multiple threads efficient?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, cat

I have a multi-threaded C++11 program in which each thread produces a large amount of data that need to be written to the disk. All the data need to be written onto one file. At the moment, I use a mutex that protects accesses to the file from multiple threads. My friend suggested me that I can use one file for each thread, then at the end merge the files into one file with `cat` command done from C++ code using `system()`.
I'm thinking if `cat` command is going to read all the data back from the disk and then write it again to the disk but this time into a single file, it's not going to be any better. I have googled but couldn't find `cat` command implementation details. May I know how it works and if it's going to accelerate the whole procedure?

**Edit:**
Chronology of events is not important, and there's no ordering constraint on the contents of the files. Both methods will perform what I want.

Comment: The two methods are not equivalent. You'll have a chronology of events when multiple threads are writing to the same file. If you write to multiple and then concatenate you'll lose that. If that's not important to you, you should mention that in the question.

Comment: Please don't use system calls for file operations.

Comment: It breaks portability and it is easy enough using `fstream`s (or if you are using boost, `boost::filesystem`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't specify if you have some ordering or structuring constraints on the content of the file. Generally it is the case, so I'll treat it as such, but hopefully my solution should work either way.

**The classical programmatic approach**

The idea is to offload the work of writing to disk to a dedicated IO thread, and have a multiple producers/ one consumer queue to queue up all the write commands. Each work thread simply format its output as a string and push it back to the queue. The IO thread pop batches of messages from the queue into a buffer, and issue the write commands.

Alternatively, you could add a field in your messages to indicate which worker emitted the write command, and have the IO thread push to different files, if needed.

For better performance, it also interesting to look into async versions of the IO system primitives (read/write), if your host OS supports them. The IO thread would then be able to monitor several concurrent IO, and feed the OS with new ones as soon as one terminate.

As it has been advised in comments, you will have to monitor the IO thread for congestion situations, and tune the number of workers accordingly. The "natural" feedback based mechanism is to simply make the queue bounded, and workers will wait on the lock until space free up on it. This let you control the amount of produced data at any point during the process life, which is an important point in memory constrained scenarios.

**Your `cat` concerns**

As for `cat`, [this command line tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29) simply read whatever is wrote to its input channel (usually `stdin`), and duplicates it to its output (`stdout`). It's as simple a that, and you can clearly see the similarity with the solution advocated above. The difference is that `cat` doesn't understand the file internal structure (if any), it only deals with byte streams, which means that if several processes write concurrently to a `cat` input *without synchronization*, the resulting output would probably be completely mixed up. Another issue is the [atomicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220525/is-fwrite-atomic) (or lack thereof) of IO primitives.

---

NB: On some systems, there's a neat little feature called a [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28file_system%29), which let you have several "independent" streams of data multiplexed in a single file. If you happen to work on a platform supporting that feature, you could have all your data streams bundled in a single file, but separately reachable.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of such solution. I have a memory usage constraint (maybe I had to mention it in the question). IO thread queue may end up consuming (probably unpredictable) memory space, and I have to avoid using disk space as memory.

Comment: @didierc: True.  The main thing is that it's faster for 1 thread to write to 1 file then for multiple threads to contend over write access to that file.  It may also be worth mentioning that the single writer thread shouldn't be too much slower than the worker threads, as big result objects could take up lots of memory in the queue (mentioning this because it's happening to me right now; then again I'm doing it in Java so mem impact harder to manage :-) )  This can always be managed by tuning to reduce the number of worker threads until throughput stops increasing.

Comment: @Farzad I was writing my comment above before I read yours.  I have been having the same problem.  Try tuning to reduce the number of worker threads.  It seems counterintuitive but you will see throughput improvement as results will not overwhelm memory by being queued faster than they can be written.  Keep reducing until you find you are actually losing throughput.  Also, take a good look at your writer thread and try to find optimizations (e.g. reduce the complexity of output formatting, etc.)

Comment: @sparc_thread, yes, or limit the size of the queue, forcing workers to block when it's full (though that would boils down to the original solution, though the multplexing would be done by the IO thread instead of the OS).

Comment: @Farzad, unfortunately, the data produced by the workers will have to go somewhere, either temporary files, or a memory buffer (the queue). Indeed it'll be a matter of tuning the number of workers so that the IO thread doesn't get overwhelmed.

Comment: @Farzard:  Yes that is correct.  I am not as familiar w/ C++11 provided concurrent data structures but I imagine by this time the new libraries would include a blocking queue.

Comment: @Farzad:  just realized something else, you will need a blocking queue anyway for managing the concurrent access to the queue by workers and the writer, and because the writer will be blocking on reading the queue when it is empty.  WHICH REMINDS ME:  make sure when workers are done, something (the thread that dispatches the workers?) puts a message onto the queue telling the writer thread that no more messages are coming. That way the writer thread will know not to block on the empty queue anymore and can shut down.